# Intuition behind disc notation

Tags: general-topology

I am told that $\overline{D}\left(y,r\right)=\left\{ x\mid\left\Vert x-y\right\Vert \leq r\right\}$ is a closed disk centered at $y$. But I don't understand why the center is at $y$ and not $x$, and where the $\left\Vert x-y\right\Vert$ part comes from, both why we have to use the norm symbols and why you subtract $x - y$ and not $y - x$ or some other operation (why subtraction in particular?)

Comment: Try to get some understanding with an example. E.g. what comes out for the disk if you take $y=0$ (i.e. $y$ is the origin) and $r=1$? Don't you recognize that as the closed unit disk, centered at the origin? Here $\overline{D}\left(0,1\right)=\left\{ x\mid\left\Vert x\right\Vert \leq1\right\} $.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to think that some set defined in terms of $y$ and $r$ is a something centered "on $x$". $x$ is only a variable name used inside the definition of $D(y,r)$.

Comment: Because the formula is pretty much a literal translation of "the set of points whose distance from $y$ is less than or equal to $r$, just with "distance" replaced by a formula that computes distance.

Comment: $x$ is a bound variable, so cannot be "the" centre. $y$ is the free parameter here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set consists of all points $x$, for which $||x-y||$ (the "distance" between $x$ and $y$) is smaller than or equal to $r$, the "radius". In this sense, this set is the same as a disk, which consists of all points which have a distance smaller than or equal to the radius to the center.

Comment: Why can't the set consist of all points $x$ for which $\|y - x\| \leq r$? Why does it have to be $x - y$?

Comment: but $\|y-x\|=\|x-y\|$

Comment: AnalysisStudent0414 is right, the distance is symmetric! So it doesn't matter which of the two you write.

Answer (score 1):

Think about a circle in Euclidean geometry, how do you define it? The set of all points on the plane that are at distance less than or equal to $r$ from a fixed point $P$.

You're doing the exact same thing here, remembering that in a normed space $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|=\|y-x\|$

So what you're writing is the same as
$$\overline{D}(y,r)=\{x \; | \; d(x,y)\leq r \}$$

Comment: oops, good point